exporting vertex colors to gltf
I am trying to export animated geometry from Blender to Bevy with vertex colors via gltf.
In a test scene, i can create a sphere and paint the vertex colors, export as gltf with attributes enabled and it includes an attribute called COLOR_O:
"meshes":[
        {
            "name":"Icosphere",
            "primitives":[
                {
                    "attributes":{
                        "POSITION":0,
                        "NORMAL":1,
                        "TEXCOORD_0":2,
                        "COLOR_0":3
                    },
                    "indices":4
                }
            ]
        }
    ],

I am then able to read the data in the game engine.
Now I want to do this for an animated mesh, so I repeat the same process, but the attribute is not present in the gltf:
"meshes":[
        {
            "name":"RoadKillOut__0",
            "primitives":[
                {
                    "attributes":{
                        "_CUSTOM":0,
                        "_INDEX":1,
                        "POSITION":2,
                        "NORMAL":3,
                        "TEXCOORD_0":4,
                        "JOINTS_0":5,
                        "WEIGHTS_0":6
                    },
                    "indices":7,
                    "material":0
                }
            ]
        }
    ],

In both cases the color attribute is visible in Blender under Color Attribute / Attribute of type FaceCorner -> Byte Color
Or in the spreadsheet in Mesh / Face Corner / Attribute
But it doesn't get exported in the animated scene.
I tried deleting that attribute on the test sphere scene, and that caused the export to lack the attribute, so it's definitely this attribute that I'm looking for.
The animated scene is a skinned mesh on an armature, under a hierarchy, if that is relevant:


The GLTF exporter addon is developed by KhronosGroup on Github not by the Blender Foundation and questions about it should be asked here.

@JohnEason That's the Khronos issue tracker, not for questions/answers.  Asking questions in any Q&A forum is fine, and some of the developers of the addon even keep an eye on the gltf tag here on Blender StackEchange.

@emackey Fair enough. It sounds as if the problem wasn't anything to do with the exporter anyway in this case.

Turns out I had to select the mesh named "RoadKillOut_O" (not my name) and unlink it from "Scene_-_Root"
I am a Blender novice and I don't really know what the implications of this are, but the animations still work and now it exports as desired.
